# Wireless disconnects when computer heats up.

Tags: wireless

Lately my computer has been disconnecting from my Wifi network. I can tell it isn't an external problem since my cellphone connects perfectly. I used to run

`sudo service network-manager restart`

and everything would return to normal. Now I do such a thing and no Wi-Fi networks are displayed after the reboot. I tried editing the NetworkManager.conf file to

`managed=true`

but nothing really changed. What other options do I have? So far, the only thing that works is rebooting, and then I get a stable connection for a few minutes.

**UPDATE** I replaced the Network Manager with WICD, and things were more stable. After several observations, I am pretty sure the Wi-Fi goes down when there is a slight temperature rise. For example, when running matlab and performing computations, the laptop fan starts to work and heat-up, and then I loose the Wi-Fi connection. Whatsmore, I cannot get the Wi-Fi to relaunch after I turn it off.

iwconfig result:

```
th0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Gaia"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: F4:F2:6D:8E:DE:09   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=17 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:2484   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Use `iwconfig` to find your Wifi device name. Search for that name in `/var/log/kern.log`. E.g. if your Wifi device name is `wlan0`, `grep wlan0 /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: @waltinator Is "IEEE 802.11bgn" a device name? That's what I'm reading next to wlan0 in the iwconfig screen.

Comment: No, `wlan0` is the device name.

Comment: Please edit the question to include `iwconfig` resultd

Comment: @waltinator OK. I am getting a lot of hits.

Comment: Yes, and it's up to you to read the messages. Some of them might explain why your Wifi is dropping.

Comment: The number of retries and invalids suggest interference. What channel is your wireless set for? Is your connection using WPA2-AES? (set your NetworkManager.conf file back to default).

Comment: @heynnema I'm using a replicator for the router is far away. I downloaded wicd and things seems to be Ok.

Comment: Then answer your own question, wait 2 days, and click the accept checkmark to close the question.

Comment: @heynnema Well, I will give it some time to see if the connection is indeed stable.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you care to answer my earlier questions? And, what brand/kind of repeater are you using? If you turn off your repeater, and move closer to your router, does the signal stay stable?

Comment: @heynnema I'm using WPA. I don't know how to check what channel the wireless is set for.

Comment: Both WPA2-AES encryption, and the wireless channel, are set in the router, and probably also in your repeater. Log into the admin pages to check the settings. You didn't say what brand/kind of repeater you have, or my last question.

Comment: @heynnema I'll update in a while. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the post. Regards,

Comment: Your update didn't add much to what troubleshooting has to be done. First we have to temporarily eliminate the repeater as the problem. Power it **OFF**, move your computer closer to the wireless router, and see if you can maintain a reliable connection. Report back.